# Cells in a table are not enclose

Tags: tables, pdftex

Here are my codes.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
 \Xhline{0.8pt}
%  \cline{1-8}
%  \diagbox{Estimator}{AUC}

  \\& \makecell{ MLE } & \makecell{Ridge  } &\makecell{ Lasso }&\makecell{James-Stein} & \makecell{Empirical\\Bayes}  \\
\hline 
AUC &\makecell{ 0.66 }&\makecell{ 0.66}  &\makecell{0.67 }&\makecell{ 0.75} & \makecell{0.74 }   \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{AUC computed by shrinkage estimators} \label{auctab1}
\hfill \break
\end{document}
```

I wonder why the cells are not enclosed. Which parameter affect on this and how can I fix it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You should enclose the `tabularx`-environment and the `\caption` command in an environment. Either `table` or, if you don't want floats, `minipage`. The way it is now is no good, because it might happen, that the caption ends up on the next page and not beneath the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from the first `\\` you got in your table. The vertical lines are just inserted for cells which exist, and in that line there is only one cell, so only one line is inserted. This is true for every line which doesn't have enough cells in that table (just insert a `\\` anywhere to see the effect). Therefore your issue is fixed by inserting the missing cells or removing that row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
 \Xhline{0.8pt}
  &&&&&\\% Note the leading &s in this line
  & \makecell{ MLE } & \makecell{Ridge  } &\makecell{ Lasso }&\makecell{James-Stein} & \makecell{Empirical\\Bayes}  \\
\hline 
AUC &\makecell{ 0.66 }&\makecell{ 0.66}  &\makecell{0.67 }&\makecell{ 0.75} & \makecell{0.74 }   \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{AUC computed by shrinkage estimators} \label{auctab1}
\end{table}
\hfill \break
\end{document}
```

[image]